# Ajax / js on refresh, limit content shown/gotten from php/sql

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

So long story short, im trying to build a chat application....well its already built kind of but, ive been trying to implement AJAX into it. Essentially so that as the messages come through from the db when a user posts it, that it reflects on the page automatically without page refresh.

on the javascript side the only event i could think of that would run without user input is the javascript setInterval() function that i have set to repeat @ every 5 seconds for now.

on the PHP side which has the messages (echoed out), i have a statement that only displays the
last 10 messages.

The problem is that, every 5 seconds, it spits out the same 10 messages. over and over...broken record kinda lol. anyways so what i dont know/cant figure out how to implement, is a filter kind of, or ***SOMEthing*** that says "

> hey only show me the last 10 messages and update ONLY when there is
>   new content.

"

So what i need is something( i assume javascript since its the one refreshing the page) that says only display the latest x posts only when its new content. I was thinking maybe an if/else that compares one value to another and then if false/true, run the refresh...but 
what do i compare to???

as you can see, im stuck.

i dont post the code because its alot...dont want to put two chunks of code here but essentially the PHP reads rows from a DB section, and posts the latest 10 posts from the db via echo.

and the Js has AJAx commands that gets those messages and posts them on the page.

And again, both work except for the re-posting the same 10 messages on ajax /js refresh.

any tips,links, LOGIC...anything to help me get through this hump i gladly and humbly appreciate.

P.S - if you need to see code. let me know and ill post it but i think its pretty clear.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a last returned timestamp in your javascript, and when you need to update the clients, send that along, and use that as your sql conditions:

```
select * from chat_logs WHERE datetime > $postedValueFromClient # AND YOUR OTHER CONDITIONS
```

Give that query results back to your clients, and update the last timestamp as well.

I can't help you further since I don't have any code, but that's one way of implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

so webchat clients do this thing where they make a request to the server and the server lets it hang, as if its taking a long time to process, but instead, its waiting to see if someone else posts a chat or what have you, the moment it does, it replies to the user, if the timeout max is reached, it just allows the connection to actually timeout, at which point the javascript causes it to fire again. this eliminates the nasty, make a call every 5 sec feature for starters.

Comment: yeah i was thinking about this but..was gonna try to tackle later on...how do you suggest going about this? i mean, id still have to hit up the server for a request right?

Comment: so yes, you still have to hit the server, but you have the server loop with a while loop or similar, while checking for new messages, if it doesn't find any within a timeout, break the loop. This solves the once every 5 sec problem anyways.

Comment: THANK YOU lol....logic is great.So what would be a good coutner? like..to compare against? reason i ask is, i need some way to know when a message is the last one. then i can compare and either break out of the loop or post...problem is i need that ONE thing to compare against and not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'd fetch 1 line at a time and remember the ID of the last line that was received, also make a column in your table for instance `read` and set it to `1` or `0`, if the message was receive set to `1` and only look for messages that have read set to `0`.

MySQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` > `lastID` AND `read` = 0;
```